# creating data tables passing data to the view code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

i see that to  make database tables appear, something like

```
$dataToBePassed = //SOME QUERY
```

`$this->load->view('viewpage', $dataToBePassed);` is used to

but how would i do it with templating?

like I have this to load the view into my template

```
  $data['content_view'] = 'viewpage';
  $this->templates->admin_template($data);
```

then will be passed to

```
//templates html codes
       <?php $this->load->view($content_view); ?>
//templates html codes
```

how do i make

```
//templates html codes
       <?php $this->load->view($content_view); ?>
//templates html codes
```

like this

```
//templates html codes
   <?php $this->load->view($content_view, $data); ?>﻿
//templates html codes
```

Comment: what error display in your coding ?

Comment: you can use , are u getting any error?

Comment: no errors but yesterday i didnt know what i did but i think i clicked something from the inspect element error and it shows the template disformed and the body says `'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read', $data, FALSE.php` not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller

```
$data['view'] = 'your_view';
$data['content'] = $this->Model->fn_model();
$this->load->view('themplate',$data)
```

View

```
<?php print_r($content); ?> // $content form $data['content']
```

Comment: print_r($content); shows the values i wanted. but how do i pass it?

Comment: $this->load->view('themplate', $data)

sry man i forgot this line

Comment: press F12 on Browser for open Developer Mode and find your error

Comment: yes. i already did it. it says jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/TLC_HR/Job_Titles/ajaxPaginationData/10 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: i am using a open source templates so i dont know how to work this out.

Comment: i dont know what happenned man but right now i cannot see that error. but still not working